# Kotlin custom exception add message sequently

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created my exceptions as below and it works fine.

```
open class MyException(message: String): Exception(message)

class MyException1(message: String): MyException(message)
class MyException2(message: String): MyException(message)
class MyException3(message: String): MyException(message)

fun process1() {
    throw MyException1("from process1")
}

fun process2() {
    try {
        process1()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        if ( e is MyException ) throw e
    }
}


fun main() {
    process2()
}
```

#### Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" MyException1: from process1
 at FileKt.process1 (File.kt:8) 
 at FileKt.process2 (File.kt:13) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:22)
```

I want to add the `process-2` message to the error message in the `process2` function without changing the type.

This is what i want to achive:

```
Exception in thread "main" MyException1: from process2 | from process1
 at FileKt.process1 (File.kt:8) 
 at FileKt.process2 (File.kt:13) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:22)
```

> I dont want to use data class for Exceptions